# Content-based plugin not loading

Tags: joomla-3.4, articles, administrator, custom-field

I'm pretty new to plugin creation and I've already hit a snag. I'm trying to add fields to the admin-side article creation via plugin but nothing is showing up in $params signifying proper loading and a die('testing...') in the plugin methods does not fire. Was hoping to get a fresh pair of eyes on this to see what I'm doing incorrectly.

articlepublishemail/articlepublishemail.php:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

class plgContentArticlepublishemail extends JPlugin
{
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    function __construct(& $subject, $config)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject,$config);
        $this->loadLanguage();
    }

    function onContentPrepareForm($form,$data)
    {
        ...
        switch($option)
        {
            case 'com_content' :
                if ($app->isAdmin())
                {
                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                    $form->loadFile('content',false);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

articlepublishemail/articlepublishemail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<files>
    <folder>language</folder>
    <folder>forms</folder>
    <filename plugin="articlepublishemail">articlepublishemail.php</filename>
</files>    
<languages>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.plg_content_articlepublishemail.ini</language>
</languages>      
<config>
    <fields name="params">
    </fields>
</config>
```

articlepublishemail/forms/content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
<fields name="attribs">
    <fieldset name="articlepublishemail" label="PLG_CONTENT_ARTICLEPUBLISHEMAIL_FIELDSET_LABEL">
        <field
            name="email_send"
            type="radio"
            default="0"
            label="PLG_CONTENT_ARTICLEPUBLISHEMAIL_EMAIL_SEND_LABEL">
            <option value="0">JOFF</option>
            <option value="1">JON</option>
        </field>
        <field
            name="email_sendto"
            type="text"
            label="PLG_CONTENT_ARTICLEPUBLISHEMAIL_EMAIL_SENDTO_LABEL"
        />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
</form>
```

I've changed the names of fields and fieldsets several times trying to get something positive going and nothing. I don't entirely understand how the directory structure for a plugin is supposed to work either so that could be it...Either way, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled the plugin the via Plugin Manager?

Comment: There is a full guide on how to do this on Joomla's website. You can find it here: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component . Have you used this guide for the implementation?

Comment: @itoctopus yes, I've used that among a few other guides (where applicable).

Comment: @Lodder Y'know, I got so caught up trying to code the darn thing that I completely forgot about any other steps that might be involved...Enabling the plugin might have helped. Would you kindly turn that into a formal answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins, like other Joomla extensions, must be **enabled** in order work and the code be executed.

Please ensure you've enabled it, by going to the Plugin Manager via the Joomla backend.